# Can't reconfigure Xorg

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, debian-jessie, nvidia-graphics-card

I made a common mistake of not reading the whole manual and installing Nvidia drivers.  Now Xorg won't even start.  I read that reconfiguring Xorg fixes that but it's not working for me.

My system:

- Debian 8.0.0 Jessie
- Laptop with Intel HD Graphics and Nvidia GeForce 540m with Nvidia Optimus.

When I tried `dpkg-reconfigure x11-common`, I got this error message:

> update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults.

Comment: have you tried `sudo X -configure`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you remove the nvidia drivers and retry this. Installing Nvidia drivers with optimius support is tricky. You will need bumblebee, you could still use *only* the nvidia card (or *only* the intel one) without bumbleebee. 
Try

```
update-alternatives --config glx
```

Which should let you select between the two cards. When you select the nvidia card you can use nvidia-xconfig to automatically set up your xorg.conf. nvidia-xconfig can be downloaded from the repository

**Removing Nvidia Drivers:**

If you installed the nvidia drivers from the official repositories, what you need to do is:

```
apt-get autoremove nvidia*
```

If you installed the drivers by manually downloading them from the nVidia website, then what you will want to do is run

```
nvidia-uninstaller
```

Your next step will be to revert any changes made to your xorg.conf configuration file. By default it is empty on Jessie (unless im mistaken).

```
cd /etc/X11/
rm xorg.conf
rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf
```

Now; when installing the nVidia drivers the built in nouveau drivers are disabled by the addition of a file which blacklists. To re-enable nouveau you will have to remove a file that was generated by the nVidia installation. One of the files in **/etc/modprobe** will have a line that reads **blacklist nouveau**. Delete that line, save the file and then run the command

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Finall just reinstall the nouveau drivers to make sure nvidia has not overwritten anything

```
aptitude install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau and xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

This should revert what the nVidia installation might have done.

Answer (score 0):

The package you need are
libdrm-intel1 for Intel drivers
libdrm-nouveau2 for Nvidia drivers

And check on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau and xserver-xorg-video-intel

Remove all package with nvidia name

And check your blacklist

If you want to have support with optimus, take a look on primus package